# why this database error coming in codeigniter 2?

Tags: codeigniter

I have table name 'articles' in mysql  mydb i am still getting this error when entering data into the database why ?

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1146

Table 'mydb.artilces' doesn't exist
```

Comment: had to read this twice to check it wasn't a joke question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

table name is wrong

> artiLCes is not artiCLes